# How is this safety element going to prevent kickback on a sliding panel table saw?

Tags: table-saw, safety, kickback

I have a sliding panel table saw with the following safety element:

[image]

The user's manual says that:

- this thingy is here to prevent kickback
- you can mount it either at the head or the back of the sliding panel

Unfortunately, I did not find an English version, but that is all it says.

[image]

In videos and on the manufacturer's pictures I see the item facing either the blade, or the operator.

I really cannot imagine how this thing can prevent kickback. Do you have any ideas?

EDIT

@bowlturner The safety element is mounted on a sliding panel which in turn moves the piece against the blade. I did not have another photo, but I drew it on this one in red.

[image]

Comment: What is the piece of equipment you have it mounted on?  I'm having a hard time visualizing how it works from that photograph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see how that would work to prevent kickback in any ripping operation (and obviously the riving knife is there to help with that<sup>1</sup>).

I'm very much not sure but this could be intended for crosscutting. However, I think it's only of significant value when a workpiece is being held incorrectly (in the less-safe orientation) relative to the sliding table's backstop.

Related explanation in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1mnb2HuH9Rw) Kuffys Woodwork video, from 11:09 onwards.

---

A general point, IMO all features of major power tools should be covered by the documentation. And I think it is a very large oversight<sup>2</sup> when a safety feature *that may save **serious** injury* is not explained or its use clearly illustrated in the manual or in an associated webpage/PDF document.

---

<sup>1</sup> Just an observation, the fitted riving knife seems unusually tall.

<sup>2</sup> Bordering on criminal negligence!

Answer (score 2):

If you can mount it turned 180° so the ramp part faces the blade instead of you, I can see where you would place your wood just short of the blade then slide this piece against the back of the wood, *sort of* clamping it or bracing it with this. If there is any kick back, the wood would rise up and hit the metal piece, stopping (one hopes) instead of continuing to fly back into your face.